# ASP NET Core reading complex configuration with array and JsonConverter

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-core, abstract-class, appsettings

I have this appsettings.json

```
"TopLevel": [
    {
      "Name": "Name",
      "TopChild": {
        "File": {
          "URL": "SomeUrl",
          "Username": "Admin",
          "Password": "123"
        }
      },
      "TopChild2": [
        {
          "Name": "SimpleMapper",
          "Mapper": {
            "Param1": "",
            "Param2": "",
            "Param3": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "Name": "SimpleFileConverter",
          "Converter": {
            "ToWhat": "",
            "Writer": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "TopChild3": {
        "SomeProperty3": {
          "WhatIsThis": "",
          "SomeProp": "",
          "Password": ""
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Name",
      "TopChild": {
        "DB": {
          "ConnectionString": "String",
          "Username": "Admin",
          "Password": "123"
        }
      },
      "TopChild2": [
        {
          "Name": "SomeConverter",
          "Converter": {
            "Param1": "",
            "Param2": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "Name": "SimpleFileConverter",
          "Mapper": {
            "Param1": "",
            "Param2": "",
            "Param3": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "TopChild3": {
        "SomePropety4": {
          "SomeProp7": "",
          "Password": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

And this is the code I wrote for a model

```
public class TopLevelConfigRoot
        {
            [JsonProperty("TopLevel")]
            public List<TestObject> TopLevel { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestObject
        {
            [JsonProperty("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("TopChild")]
            [JsonConverter(typeof(TopChildConverter))]
            public TopChildBase TopChild { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("TopChild2")]
            [JsonConverter(typeof(TopChild2Converter))]
            public List<TopChild2> TopChild2 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("TopChild3")]
            [JsonConverter(typeof(TopChild3Converter))]
            public TopChild3Base TopChild3 { get; set; }
        }

        public abstract class TopChildBase { }
        public abstract class TopChild3Base { }

        public class File : TopChildBase
        {
            [JsonProperty("URL")]
            public string URL { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Username")]
            public string Username { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }

        public class DB : TopChildBase
        {
            [JsonProperty("ConnectionString")]
            public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Username")]
            public string Username { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }

        public interface ITopChild2
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public ITopChild2Type ITopChild2Type { get; set; }
        }

        public class TopChild2 : ITopChild2
        {
            [JsonProperty("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ITopChild2Type")]
            public ITopChild2Type ITopChild2Type { get; set; }
        }

        public abstract class ITopChild2Type
        { }

        public class Mapper : ITopChild2Type
        {
            [JsonProperty("Param1")]
            public string Param1 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Param2")]
            public string Param2 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Param3")]
            public string Param3 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Converter : ITopChild2Type
        {
            [JsonProperty("Param1")]
            public string Param1 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Param2")]
            public string Param2 { get; set; }
        }

        public class SomeProperty3 : TopChild3Base
        {

            [JsonProperty("WhatIsThis")]
            public string WhatIsThis { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("SomeProp")]
            public string SomeProp { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }

        public class SomePropety4 : TopChild3Base
        {
            [JsonProperty("SomeProp7")]
            public string SomeProp7 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

        }


        public class TopChildConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType == typeof(TopChildBase);
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

                if (jo.ContainsKey(nameof(File)))
                {
                    return jo[nameof(File)].ToObject<File>();
                }
                else if (jo.ContainsKey(nameof(DB)))
                {
                    return jo[nameof(DB)].ToObject<DB>();
                }
                return null;
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public class TopChild3Converter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType == typeof(TopChild3Base);
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

                if (jo.ContainsKey(nameof(SomeProperty3)))
                {
                    return jo[nameof(SomeProperty3)].ToObject<SomeProperty3>();
                }
                else if (jo.ContainsKey(nameof(SomePropety4)))
                {
                    return jo[nameof(SomePropety4)].ToObject<SomePropety4>();
                }
                return null;
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public class TopChild2Converter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType == typeof(TopChild2);
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                JArray ja = JArray.Load(reader);

                List<TopChild2> topChild2List = new List<TopChild2>();
                foreach (var item in ja)
                {
                    JObject jObject = (JObject)item;

                    TopChild2 TopChild2 = null;

                    string name = jObject[nameof(TopChild2.Name)].ToString();

                    if (jObject.ContainsKey(nameof(Mapper)))
                    {
                        var root = jObject[nameof(Mapper)];

                        Mapper mapper = new Mapper
                        {
                            Param1 = root[nameof(Mapper.Param1)].Value<string>(),
                            Param2 = root[nameof(Mapper.Param2)].Value<string>(),
                            Param3 = root[nameof(Mapper.Param3)].Value<string>()
                        };

                        TopChild2 = new TopChild2 { Name = name, ITopChild2Type = mapper };
                    }
                    else if (jObject.ContainsKey(nameof(Converter)))
                    {
                        var root = jObject[nameof(Converter)];

                        Converter converter = new Converter
                        {
                            Param1 = root[nameof(Converter.Param1)].Value<string>(),
                            Param2 = root[nameof(Converter.Param2)].Value<string>()
                        };

                        TopChild2 = new TopChild2 { Name = name, ITopChild2Type = converter };
                    }

                    topChild2List.Add(TopChild2);
                }
                return topChild2List;
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

And now with that model I've tried using any known implementation of config inside of controller.

The only thing I came up is inserting IConfiguration via Dependency Injection and use _config = config;

And then selected it by

```
var section = _config.GetSection("TopLevel");
```

and then used it like this

```
var itemArray = section.AsEnumerable();
```

How can I then use this itemArray to convert this to either model, or a JsonString which i will then easily serialize it with Newtonsoft

```
var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopLevelConfigRoot>(jsonString);
```

But I haven't find a way to map this itemArray to model I provided, nor I had success with writing recursive method to actually map it to JsonString.

Converter I wrote is

```
    public string ConvertBackToJSonString(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] itemArray)
    {
        var root = new JObject();
        var current = root;

        foreach (var item in itemArray)
        {
            var parts = item.Key.Split(':');
            var key = parts[parts.Length - 1];
            var parent = current;

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                var part = parts[i];
                if (!current.ContainsKey(part))
                    current.Add(part, new JObject());
                current = (JObject)current[part];
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
                current.Add(key, new JValue(item.Value));
            else
                current.Add(key, new JObject());

            current = parent;
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

But that didn't work. How should this be approached to/done?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the section to a model directly with IConfigration.Bind() method

For example,in your case :

```
public class BindTarget
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public SomeChildClass1 TopChild { get; set; }
        public List<SomeChildClass2> TopChild2 { get; set; }
        public SomeChildClass3 TopChild3 { get; set; }

    }

    public class SomeChildClass1
    {
        public File File { get; set; }
        public DB  DB { get; set; }
    }
    public class SomeChildClass2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Mapper Mapper { get; set; }

        public Converter Converter { get; set; }
    }
    public class SomeChildClass3
    {
        public SomeProperty3 SomeProperty3 { get; set; }
        public SomePropety4 SomePropety4 { get; set; }
    }
```

bind as below:

```
var targetobj = new List<BindTarget>();
Configuration.GetSection("TopLevel").Bind(targetobj);
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(targetobj,new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore});
```

result:
[image]

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern) related

Comment: It won't work on the code I provided. Imagine that you will have to have an 

      "TopChild": {
        "File": {
          "URL": "SomeUrl",
          "Username": "Admin",
          "Password": "123"
        }

Which can have either a File, or DB, but will not have both. You will need an abstract class. Once you introduce the abstract class, things gets complicated.

Also notice that "TopLevel": [ {}, {}] the structure of TopLevel key. The devil is in details. Please use the code I provided, and if you come up with solution, post it

Comment: Since you read the configration with _config.GetSection("TopLevel") ,topLevel is the key,won't appear in value part

Comment: Yes, but therefore I've did section.AsEnumerable(); so that I could read N values of the array. Please use the appsettings that I've provided, the binding that you provided is not working for me. Give it a try

Comment: And I think you should learn about abstract class first,abstruct class is designed to be inherited,it could not be instanced,which means it could never been assigned any value.so you won't read any value with your TestObject class.

Comment: Ruikai, don't know if you looked at my code. Abstract class is in this case just used to define type 

public abstract class TopChildBase { }

It is inherited on two objects, if you know how Deserialization of Json is working, you know that this is the way to have highly flexible configuration model that will deserialized json config to the same model without creating properties that will have null value. In other words I will not have to have A object containing both B and C objects if I didn't define them in config. I can have just B or just C object as a property of A.

Comment: Please reread the original thread

Comment: The idea of using that abstract class is not to cary value, the idea is that I have the same type, and then via resolver it will eirther be B : A class or C : A class carrying values inside their own properties